# In flask, how can I execute a before_filter on a particular pluggable view?

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask application that is laid out as a few `MethodView`s.

On one of my MethodViews, I want to open a database connection before each request, and close it after the request, very similar to [this](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/tutorial/dbcon/).

I know how to use global `@app.before_request` and `@app.teardown_request` functions, but those will run for every single request. I want limited versions that will only run for the routes in a particular MethodView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a decorator, that would tag certain views as database dependent.

```
NoSQLStore = {}

class NoSQL(object):
    """ fake """
    def query(self, key): 
        return '%s\n' % NoSQLStore.get(key, 'no such key')
    def put(self, key, value):
        NoSQLStore[key] = value

def with_database(fn):
    """ Decorator for functions, that need database access.
        NoSQL object will be stored under ``g.db``. 
    """
    def connect_and_close(*args, **kwargs):
        g.db = NoSQL()
        __result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
        # a real database should be somehow ``closed()`` here
        return __result
    return connect_and_close

class StoreAPI(MethodView):

    @with_database
    def get(self):
        return g.db.query(request.args.get('key'))

    @with_database
    def post(self):
        key, value = str(random.randint(0, 1000)), str(random.randint(0, 1000))
        g.db.put(key, value)
        return 'set %s => %s\n' % (key, value)
```

A runnable standalone example can be found here: https://gist.github.com/4424587

Comment: +1 I like the decorator approach. MethodViews have a way to apply the decorator to every action automatically (http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/views/#decorating-views)

Answer (score 3):

If you are creating a `MethodView` subclass the easiest way to do this is to simply add a function that gets called when any of the appropriate methods are:

```
class AutoConnectingView(MethodView):
    def setup(self):
        # Connect to the database here and store the connection on self.
        self.db = connect_to_db()

    def teardown(self):
        self.db.close()

    def dispatch_request(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.setup()
        response = super(AutoConnectingView, self).dispatch_request(*args, **kwargs)
        self.teardown()
        return response


class ARoomWithAView(AutoConnectingView):
    def get(self):
        rooms = self.db.execute("SELECT * FROM RoomsWithViews")
        return render_template("rooms.html", rooms=rooms)
```